# NSMutableArray of UIImages

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uiimage, nsmutablearray

I would like to load UIImages to an array, to add them later to an UITableView.

```
- (void)imageLoader:(GGImageLoader *)imageLoader didLoadImage:(UIImage *)anImage
{
    [myArray addObject:anImage];

    [imageLoader release];
}
```

MyArray is an NSMutableArray defined in the .h File,

If I print the count of myArray its 0 everytime.

Does anybody see the problem?

Thank you in advance..

regards Dennis

Comment: It is very likely that the problem is not in this part of your code. Without knowing more, it's hard to tell, but first try to compare the address of ``myArray`` in ``imageLoader:didLoadImage:`` with the address of ``myArray`` in the routine where you try to print its count. Maybe you are adding the images to a different array, or maybe ``myArray`` is ``nil`` in the above routine.

Comment: yes, if I pass anImage to an UIImage and add this to the tableview it wors, but it should get an asyncronus load of images and so there are every time other pictures. so i have to add them to an array to get the right picture for the right entry with indexpath.row. I dont understand why the array is nil, while uiimage *testpic = anImage; works?!?

Comment: Well, I don't understand it either, but without seeing your code (including the places where ``myArray`` is initialized and where the image loader is set up), I cannot say much.

Comment: seems like if myArray is not initialized

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

1. myArray is most likely nil, which explains why its -count is 0 and adding anImage does nothing. You have to declare the pointer variable in your .h file (as you did), but where is myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]? It should be in one of your initialization methods.
2. You probably want to release anImage, not imageLoader.